# Why does '\r' (and not '\n') work to replace with a newline in 'vim'?

Tags: vim, regular-expression, vi-mode

In `vim` editor, I want to replace a newline character (`\n`) with two new line characters (`\n\n`) using `vim` command mode.

Input file content:

```
This is my first line.
This is second line.
```

- Command that I tried:

  ```
  :%s/\n/\n\n/g
  ```

  But it replaces the string with unwanted characters as

  ```
  This is my first line.^@^@This is second line.^@^@
  ```
- Then I tried the following command

  ```
  :%s/\n/\r\r/g
  ```

  It is working properly.

Can you explain why it is working fine with second command?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206404

Comment: FYI: There is also a [Vi and Vim (beta) SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Side note, you don't have to use `/` as the separator. This is more readable: `:%s;\n;\n\n;g`

Comment: Search for `\n`, replace with `\r\r`, `:% s/\n/\r\r/g`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334/911945

Answer (score 87):

Oddly enough, `\n` in vim for *replacement* does not mean newline, but null.  ASCII nul is `^@` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>).

Historically, vi replaces `^M` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) as the line-ending, which is the newline.  vim added an extension `\r` (like the C language) to mean the same as `^M`, but the developers chose to make `\n` mean null when *replacing* text.  This is inconsistent with its use in *searches*, which find a newline.

Further reading:

- [Search and replace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) (Vim wiki)
- [vim replace character to `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965883/vim-replace-character-to-n)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Jortstek That depends. The question title asks "how", but the actual question asks "why", and _that_ is explained in this answer.

Answer (score 23):

To replace 1 newline with 2 newlines:
`:%s/\n/\r\r/g`

`\n` - newline in search, null in replace

`\r` - newline in replace

Answer is in the question, author asked 'how to' in title, but 'why' in content... People enter this page looking for answer to 'how to' and you don't really expect it to be in question... took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
%s/$/^V^M/
```

where `^V` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and `^M` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

- When you type `^V` it will print a `^` char, then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> over it and then when you type the `^M` it will appear as `^M`
- The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is the standard tty *literal next* character - run the command `stty -a` to show your tty's special chars).

Comment: Indeed, the very experienced will know this for the ever required conversion from CRLF as an alternative to dropping out and using dos2unix or similar.  The Ctrl-V usage is a day 1 vi lesson.

Answer (score 7):

`vim` use `\n` to represent a null character `\0` in memory, that how `vim` handle file contain null character (while `vi` can not).

The use of `\n` only match end of line in the buffer, not the newline in the string when using in expression.

See [:h NL-used-for-Null](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#NL-used-for-Nul) and [:h CR-used-for-NL](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#CR-used-for-NL) for more details.

Comment: `g/^\(.*\)\n\1$/d` is `\n` here interpreted as a new line? Skipping `\n` will leave only the last line, instead of deleting the duplicates only. For instance `s/a b/a\nb` won't work, however, `s/a b/a\rb` will i.e. space is replaced with new line between  `a` and `b`

Answer (score 6):

Tested with Neovim (`nvim`) and `Vim` versions

```
NVIM v0.3.0
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1
```

**Remove a newline:**

```
cell
allele
rs2981578
fgfr2
```

Here, `\n` matches newlines (to *insert* a newline however, use `\r`):

```
:'<,'>s/\n/|/g

cell|allele|rs2981578|fgfr2
```

**Add a newline:**

Nope:

```
cell|allele|rs2981578|fgfr2

:'<,'>s/\n/|/g

cell^@allele^@rs2981578^@fgfr2
```

`^@` is a diacritic mark for LF (line feed; see
http://vimhelp.appspot.com/digraph.txt.html#digraphs-default)

Yes:

```
cell|allele|rs2981578|fgfr2

:'<,'>s/|/\r/g

cell
allele
rs2981578
fgfr2
```

To address the OP's question (how to replace one `\n` with two, `\n\n`), just add another `\r`:

```
cell
allele
rs2981578
fgfr2

:'<,'>s/\n/\r\r/g

cell

allele

rs2981578

fgfr2
```

... i.e. match the original newline (`\n`), and replace it with two newlines/carriage returns (`\r\r`).