# Vim is inserting ^@ when I try to insert a line break

Tags: regular-expression, vim

When I open Vim on my laptop and run regex like this:

```
:%s/foo/\n/g
```

vim inserts ^@ instead of line breaks.

This problem started happening last week. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.04. I think the problem might have started after Ubuntu installed updates.

## Things I've tried

### encoding and fileencoding

I tried setting the encoding and fileencoding to utf-8, and then to latin1, but this made no difference.

### :lang

:lang produces "Current language: "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_
TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8"

If I call vim with

```
LC_ALL=C vim foo
```

then its makes no difference, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Related: [Vim - how to replace one new line \n with two \n's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247329/vim-how-to-replace-one-new-line-n-with-two-ns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim - how to replace one new line \n with two \n's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247329/vim-how-to-replace-one-new-line-n-with-two-ns)

Answer (score 1):

\n in vim for replacement does not mean newline, but null.

Use \r instead. E.g.

```
:%s/foo/\r/g
```